# Configuring PHP for PostgreSQL and IIS

Tags: windows, postgresql, iis

I have PHP v7.2.7 and PostgreSQL v10 with IIS.

I am trying to get this to work following any advice I have been able to find on the web, but with no success. My configuration so far is as below.

`PHP.ini` extension list includes both `php_pdo_pgsql.dll` and `php_pgsql.dll`.

Both these dlls are located in the correct extensions directory according to phpinfo.

According to phpinfo the `Configuration File Path` is  "C:\Windows" and the `Loaded Configuration File` is  "C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.2\php.ini". I have the same php.ini file at both locations.

I have copied the version of libpq.dll from the lib folder of the postgresql installation to the root folder of the PHP installation.

I have added the bin folder of the postgresql installation to the Windows system search path.

Phpinfo shows that pdo_pgsql extension is loaded but not pgsql.

Can anyone please shed any light on what more I need to do?

Comment: libpq.dll tends to have several dependencies for things like openssl, compression and internationalization. Use a tool like [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to find out what those dependencies are.

Comment: I am aware of the dependencies, but assumed that adding the postgresql bin file to the system path would take care of that. However, have copied the various dlls to the php root folder. This made no difference. I have also run Dependency Walker. This highlighted a huge number of dependencies including shell32.dll for example. However, I am aware that there are only 4 dlls required for libpq.dll and I have copied all those across.